# Angular.foreach asynchronous callback not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach, promise

I am trying to detect if the foreach statement is completed together with the statements inside the foreach. From my research, many are asking to use promises. As I am implemented it, it is not executing the way I was expecting.

```
var uploadUrl = "/api/upload";
$('#add_product').closeModal();
 var promises = angular.forEach(vm.images_selected, function(value , key){
    return File_Upload.uploadFileToUrl(value, uploadUrl)
    .success(function(result){
        vm.images_selected_uploaded.push(result);
        console.log('here')
    });
})
$q.all(promises).then(function () {
    console.log('there')
    console.log(vm.images_selected_uploaded)
})
```

From the code above (let's say the value length is 2, the output will be

```
there
here
here
```

What I really wanted was **here here there**. What am I missing here?

Comment: You should move `success` to `then` in `$q.all()`.

Comment: `.forEach` should be `.map` (assuming angular.forEach/angular.map are similar functionally to array.prototype.forEach/array.prototype.map ... hmmm, no angular.map ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First problem, angular.forEach returns a reference to the first argument, so they wont be the promises you're looking for

Second problem, angular doesn't have a drop in replacement for .map

If you save the promises in the promises array, you can do this

```
var uploadUrl = "/api/upload";
$('#add_product').closeModal();
var promises = [];
angular.forEach(vm.images_selected, function(value , key){
    promises.push(File_Upload.uploadFileToUrl(value, uploadUrl)
        .success(function(result){
            vm.images_selected_uploaded.push(result);
            console.log('here')
        })
    );
})
$q.all(promises).then(function () {
    console.log('there')
    console.log(vm.images_selected_uploaded)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
var uploadUrl = "/api/upload";
$('#add_product').closeModal();
var promises = [];
angular.forEach(vm.images_selected, function(value , key){
    promises.push(File_Upload.uploadFileToUrl(value, uploadUrl));
});
$q.all(promises).then(function (results) {
    for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
       var result = results[i];
       vm.images_selected_uploaded.push(result);
       console.log('here');
    }
    console.log('there');
    console.log(vm.images_selected_uploaded);
})
```

OR Perhaps like this:

```
var uploadUrl = "/api/upload";
$('#add_product').closeModal();
 var promises = [];
 angular.forEach(vm.images_selected, function(value , key){
    var promise = File_Upload.uploadFileToUrl(value, uploadUrl);
    promise.success(function(result){
        vm.images_selected_uploaded.push(result);
        console.log('here');
    });
    promises.push(promise);
})
$q.all(promises).then(function () {
    console.log('there');
    console.log(vm.images_selected_uploaded);
})
```

Both is untested btw.

Comment: I think I have understand it. Thanks Arg0n! Your solution works like a charm!

Comment: And maybe more what you're aiming for.. This way they can finish in any order and you will get "here" in console before all is completed. The first is used more when you need all the results completed in order to do something.

Comment: You are right, I will use the first because i need the results to be completed. Thanks

Comment: this doesn't look like it changes anything ... promises is the original `vm.images_selected` array, not an array of promises - unless angular documentation lies - but, it's apparently worked, so what do I know

Comment: @JaromandaX Could you provide a link to what you are reading?

Comment: I'm reading angular documentation for [forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)

Comment: @JaromandaX, actually you are right. I will have to give the credit to you instead.

Comment: @GeneLim - it's odd that you said this works. Perhaps a timing issue giving you false hope?

Comment: @JaromandaX, the first example of his works indirectly, but when i did a few more testing, it does not return the result. It was still the previous result before entering the foreach.

Comment: Edited to be what I meant it to be. As I wrote, this was untested and I assumed returning from `forEach` would return the results as an `array`. Since this was not the case, I have updated my examples, yes.